# searching for a guide how to setup mongo_mapper, devise, haml with rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, devise

is there a full setup guide for mongo_mapper, haml, rails3 and devise, for the current git (master) branches? a lot of things changed in all of those frameworks/libs lately. i was wondering if somebody has it up and running and can share it on github or give some pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railscasts have a couple of Rails 3 specific casts on Devise setup and customizing - might be useful,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

(210 is the second cast on customizing Devise)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this isn't easily possible right now. The only versions of devise that support Rails 3 have removed the ORM adapters for MongoMapper due to MM relying on a custom validatable gem which uses a different syntax than the ActiveRecord/ActiveModel style. See this github issue: http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issuesearch?state=closed&q=mapper#issue/160

HAML, SASS, Devise and Mongoid on Rails3 however is quite simple. It's a shame because I really like both MongoMapper and Devise (I created the Rails 2 example linked earlier).

Answer (score 1):

I found an example app to use as a base for Devise and Mongomapper. It uses HAML and SASS. It's hosted on Github:

http://github.com/theshortcut/devise_mongomapper_example

Hope this is helpful - it certainly helped me.

Cheers
Kapslok

Comment: thanks for the pointer, actually this example is running on rails 2 and not on rails3 - with rails2 there are actually no problems, but i wanted to get everything up and running with rails3...